# How to make video size fills the site width

Tags: html, css

Hi guys I'm starting to build my first site in html5+css3 beign responsive as a goal but I have a problem trying to add a video after the header. Thing is I need my video fills the total website width. I try with "width:100%" it doesn't works.

It works when I remove "display:flex;" of #body, but I think I will need this property since I'm planning to add flexible boxes inside of #body, and if I want put flexible boxes inside #body I need set it to "display:flex" right? Im new in html5&css3 so please correct me if I'm wrong.

If anybody could help me that would be great. Thanks!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#"><img src="imagenes/logo.png"/></a>    
    </div>
<nav id="menuP">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">ALL PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SAMPLES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">QUOTE</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="menuS">
    <ul>
        <li id="account"><a href="#">ACCOUNT</a></li>
        <li id="shop"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
        <li id="contact"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>           
    </ul> 
</header>
<section id="body"> 
    <section id="slide">
        <video loop id="videoSlide">
            <source src="eu4_ost.webm" type="video/webm"> 
        </video>
    </section>  
</section>
<footer>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup{
display:block;
}
html{
width:100%;
background:white;
height:100%;
font-family:Helvetica;
}
body {      
display:flex;   
background:gray;
justify-content:center;
max-width:2000px;
flex-direction:column;
}
/* -------------------------------- HEADER ------------------------------------ */
header{
width:100%;     
background:#fabe06;    
display: flex;
justify-content: center;    
height:70px;
}
header nav ul{      
    list-style:none;
}
/* ----------------------------------- LOGO ------------------------------------- */
#logo{
    margin:0px 0px 0px 32px;
    width:260px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;             
}
    #logo img{
        width:100%;             
    }
/* ----------------------------- MENU PRINCIPAL ---------------------------------- */
#menuP{
    display:flex;       
    font-family:Patua One;
    font-size:17px;
    flex:2;
    margin:0 50px;
    justify-content:center;         
    align-items:center      
}
#menuP ul li{       
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 15px;      
}
#menuP ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;            
}
/* ----------------------------- MENU SECUNDARIO ---------------------------------- */
#menuS{

    flex:1;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:flex-end;
}
#menuS ul{
    display:flex;
}
#menuS ul li a{
    height:70px;        
    width:70px;     
    display:inline-block;               
    border-left:solid 1px;
    border-color:#eab309;       
    text-indent:-99999px;
    /*background:yellow;*/
}   
#menuS ul li a{

}
header nav ul li#account a{
    background-image:url(imagenes/account.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center; 
    background-size:20%;
}
header nav ul li#shop a{
    background-image:url(imagenes/shop.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:25%;        
}
header nav ul li#contact a{
    background-image:url(imagenes/contact.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:25%;
}
/*---------------------------- BODY -------------------------*/
#body {
width:100%;
background:yellow;
display:flex;
flex-grow:1;
}
#videoSlide{    
width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so pretty simple, the thing is that even though the video has the `width: 100%` property, its parent does not. The percentage unit is used based on the parent's width or height, so if the parent is not full page width it won't work.

Just add this to your `style.css`:

```
#slide
{
width: 100%;
}
```

Also, just noticed you never closed the `<nav>` element `.menuS` so I'd do that if I were you to avoid further trouble.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had forgotten the logic of the percentages xD... and close the <nav> element as well lol.

Answer (score 0):

Use two divs in the body and remove flex from body.

First div is video

Second is flex with main content